# What books are good about reproducing physical experiments?

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations

I want to know a book that minutely describes how to perform thousands of experiments in todays lab, the equipments required, etc.

I need to perform the Young's interference experiment.

Comment: Details are always in the eyes of the beholder: that is, what I know how to do is easy, since I know how to do it. That said, finding great detail on thousands of experiments won't be easy or in one place. Many lab instructions are online. And, there is much good learning in just the trying. As for Young's slits, a laser pointer and a micrometer/shim gauges get you single slit very easily. Two slits require a little more work.

Comment: Experiment is a craft, and it is harder (by far) to write clearly on how one decides what to do than it is to teach another person by apprenticeship. That is not to say that there are no such books, but is to say that good ones are few and far between. Detailed instruction for single experiments are fairly easy to come by, but the craft comes in knowing how to adapt them when your kit differs from that of the writer.

Comment: certainly no experimentalist would write up thousands of experiments, as the book would be huge and experimentalists are busy people, and if they are not busy they are not experimentalists. it has to be from the horses mouth after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Experiments in Modern Physics, by Adrian C. Melissinos and Jim Napolitano***

The author details the most fundamental experiments in modern physics, performing  an integration with matlab for data analysis and display

This book is accessible to beginning undergrad students, yet still theoretically rich enough for advanced experimental practice.

It can be used as a lab manual.

Comment: It's a wonderful book but it should be noted that the target audience is more junior or senior level undergrads at best. Many departments use this one for their senior or first year grad student labs.

Answer (score 3):

Exploring Quantum Physics through Hands-on Projects 1st Edition by David and Shanni Prutchi

Build an intuitive understanding of the principles behind quantum mechanics through practical construction and replication of original experiments With easy-to-acquire, low-cost materials and basic knowledge of algebra and trigonometry, Exploring Quantum Physics through Hands-on Projects takes readers step by step through the process of re-creating scientific experiments that played an essential role in the creation and development of quantum mechanics. Presented in near chronological order-from discoveries of the early twentieth century to new material on entanglement-this book includes question- and experiment-filled chapters on: * Light as a Wave * Light as Particles * Atoms and Radioactivity * The Principle of Quantum Physics * Wave/Particle Duality * The Uncertainty Principle * Schrodinger (and his Zombie Cat) * Entanglement From simple measurements of Planck's constant to testing violations of Bell's inequalities using entangled photons, Exploring Quantum Physics through Hands-on Projects not only immerses readers in the process of quantum mechanics, it provides insight into the history of the field-how the theories and discoveries apply to our world not only today, but also tomorrow. By immersing readers in groundbreaking experiments that can be performed at home, school, or in the lab, this first-ever, hands-on book successfully demystifies the world of quantum physics...

For all who seek to explore it-from science enthusiasts and undergrad physics students to practicing physicists and engineers.

Reviews :

1. This book is the best amateur science book available today. It covers a difficult subject with such mastery that the authors make it seem easy. Much effort was put forth in finding ways to make the experiments affordable. A complete listing of web sites offering surplus equipment is provided. I have not done all the experiments listed, but the ones that I have done work exactly as described. Most of the topics of quantum physics are covered in historical order, so the reader gets a sense of how the story unfolded. Many of the great and now classical experiments are included from the wave-particle duality of light through the strange phenomenon of entanglement.

Thru this book we all have a way to introduce the beauty of the micro world to our children and to ourselves. It is important to add that this was not achieved by skipping

the hard parts. David and Shanni Prutchi have found a way to make difficult ideas simple and effective without sacrificing the truth. This elegance is the heart of science itself.

2. It's an expensive book, but it is interesting, fun and inspiring. The genius of this book is in the many experiments and their explanation. Even if the reader never performed any of the experiments they go a long ways towards clarifying Quantum Mechanics (and a number of other areas of physics) beyond the average textbook and providing an intuitive "feel" for the subject. A good book.
   However, I have two complaints. The cover of the book describes the experiments as being "relatively inexpensive" and that they use "readily available" parts. Although this is true for the majority of the experiments it's not true for some of them. A few of them would require quite a bit of luck locating components even if you could afford them. The other complaint is with the publisher because even though the book is a quality product the illustrations are very small. I literally needed to keep a magnifying glass with me in order to read the illustrations and I have average eyesight.
   Nevertheless, this book delivers and if the author were to write a similar book on another topic I would be one of the first in line to buy it.

3.Dr. Prutchi simply rocks ! His explanations of each of the important physics discoveries cover the founders mindset and history followed by experiments that can be performed and verified with materials available today.

Without mind-blowing math or incomprehensible concepts, Dr. Prutchi takes you from fundamental physics to hands-on quantum experiments without missing anything.

This book is a must for anyone with an interest in science and physics. Everyone whether instructor, student, or tinkerer will learn something from his easy to understand experiments, explanations and observations of often recognizable physical behaviors.

4. While many/most of these experiments are beyond my ability to do (I'm not at all well-versed enough in electronics to set them up), I enjoyed reading this book as each and every section were written in accessible language, exploring a small segment of quantum (and some classical) physics in each "bite size" section, investigating the concept in words and calculations or experiments.

Due to its being well-written (easily understood by bright high school students) and the way it's presented in manageable chunks, it is a fun read whether one intends to do any of the hands-on activities or not.

I highly recommend this book to any serious amateur quantum physicists, as well as to people who would like a fun way to learn about the topic before pursuing it seriously at university

5. This is an excellent book for intermediate to advanced science experiments. The science is explained very well, and it's not too hard too follow. Some of the experiments require expensive equipment, but this REAL science - on the same par with the former Scientific American articles.

Some of the experiments could be dangerous - there's high vacuum, and high voltage. This book is not for the immature.

I would not recommend this for beginners; there are plenty of kid science resources out there. If you're ready for some real science, this book is for you. It conducts experiments that few others do, and I would consider it for high school and beyond. I am grateful to the authors for doing a fine job.

As an adult amateur scientist, this is perfect for me.

Also here are some links to Young's Interference Experiment.

http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-3/Young-s-Experiment

http://www.cttech.org/goodwin/academics/science-textbook/chap19.pdf